# How can I use a dynamic array for UDP receipt in D?

Tags: arrays, sockets, udp, d, dynamic-arrays

I would like to create a simple UDP server that can receive messages of varying length. However, it seems as if D's `Socket.receiveFrom()` expects a static length buffer array. When the following code runs:

```
void main() {
    UdpSocket       server_s;
    Address         client_addr;
    ubyte[]         in_buf;
    ptrdiff_t       bytesin;

    server_s = new UdpSocket();
    server_s.bind(new InternetAddress(InternetAddress.ADDR_ANY, PORT_NUM));

    bytesin = server_s.receiveFrom(in_buf, client_addr);
    if (bytesin == 0 || bytesin == Socket.ERROR) {
        writeln("Error receiving, bytesin: ", bytesin);
        return;
    }

    // Do stuff
}
```

`receiveFrom()` immediately falls through with `bytesin == 0`. Why is this? Can I even use dynamic arrays for receiving over UDP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`receive` and `receiveFrom` don't do the allocation themselves. You can pass an array of some fixed size big enough to hold any packet you expect, then slice it based on how many bytes you received.

If you preallocated 64 KB, that ought to fit everything you could conceivably get. I tend to just use 4 KB buffers though.

```d
ubyte[4096] in_buf;
bytesin = server_s.receiveFrom(in_buf, client_addr);
// check for error first then
auto message_received = in_buf[0 .. bytesin];
// process it
// keep looping, reusing the buffer, to get more stuff
```

Comment: Thanks, that does it. Should've known that's exactly what bytesin is for. This should be more well-documented behavior in the std.socket documentation. Heck, maybe they should create a version that also allocates dynamically.

Comment: The underlying OS functions need a buffer though, they work exactly the same way as these. Doing it differently would be maybe possible but tricky and of little benefit anyway... I do wish the docs called it out better with more examples though.

Comment: Basically any language requires you to allocate buffers before receive. Also you can just create your own function that does it. I don't see a reason for it to be a part of the std library.